# pubsub events in ionic framework

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I want to be able to fire events in service and let the controllers subscribe to those events, something like this in services.js

```
SomeLibrary.publish('some-channel', some_data);
```

and something like this in my controllers.js

```
SomeLibrary.subscribe('some-channel', function (data){do_something(data);});
```

so I came across https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-mediator which does precisely the same but I don't think it is supported. so, is there any way to get MediatorJs to work with ionic framework? I tried to include it in index.html like this under cordova.js import

```
<script src="lib/mediator/mediator.min.js"></script>
```

and in my app.js like this

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services', 'ngCordova','mediator-js'])
```

but it didint work too, please advise with any other alternative if its not possible to do so.

Thanks.

Comment: Mediator isn't an angular module. Adding it to your module dependencies should even throw a Module Not Found error.

I think you can pretty much achieve this by creating your own service to handle this

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the mediator.min.js with mediator.js and removed mediator-js from deps list and all worked fine.